# Optimizing an SQL statement for a number database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of over a million numbers. I need to put the numbers in one table numerically sorted, and another as is, referencing the ID of the sorted number, the table is structured as so:

sortedNumbers

```
Id | SortedNumber
1    01356
2    45789
```

Numbers

```
Id | Number | SortedNumberId
1    35601    1
2    94578    2
3    97548    2
```

Currently I am filling the sorted numbers table first, then filling the standard numbers table, and doing a select statement to get the sorted numbers Id. All these select statements are making it dog slow though, is there a way to do it all in one statement, never using a select statement to get the Id of the sorted number?

Current Queries on each iteration of a loop, sortedNumber is made by sorting the number in code

loop 1

```
query = "INSERT into SortedNumbers VALUES (" + SortedNumber + ")";
```

loop 2

```
query = "SELECT Id FROM SortedNumbers WHERE SortedNumber = " + sortedNumber;
query = "INSERT into Numbers VALUES (" + Number + ", " + SortedId + ")";
```

Comment: Sounds like this has less to do with your SQL query and more to do with missing indexes on your tables.

Comment: yeah but without the query who knows?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well for a start you don't put sorted numbers into a database.  You put the numbers into a table then query the table ordering by whatever sort criteria you want.

```
SELECT number from table ORDER BY number
```

But I expect I've missed the point of whatever you are trying to do.  Can you post some examples?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your two inserts into a  `Transaction` and get the ID value from the sortedNumbers table by calling `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.  That is assuming that the ID column in the sortedNumbers table is an Identity column:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT sortedNumbers (SortedNumber) VALUES (sortednumbervalue)
    INSERT Numbers (Number, SortedNumberId) VALUES (numbervalue, SCOPE_IDENTITY())
COMMIT
```

Comment: This is good, but what if later in the loop, a number has the same sorted value as one inserted much earlier?